# machine learning, logistic regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

```
import numpy as np
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0/(1+np.asmatrix(np.exp(-x)))

def graD(X,y,alpha,s0,numda):
    m=np.size(X,0)
    n=np.size(X,1)
    X0=X[:,0]
    X1=X[:,1:]

    theta=np.asmatrix(np.zeros(np.size(X,1))).T
    s=100
    lit=0

    while abs(s)>s0 and lit<=10000:
        theta0=theta[0]
        theta1=theta[1:]


        theta0-=(float(alpha)/m)*X0.T*(sigmoid(X*theta)-y)
        theta1-=float(alpha)*((1.0/m)*X1.T*(sigmoid(X*theta)-    y)+float(numda)/m*theta1)
        theta=np.vstack((np.asmatrix(theta0),np.asmatrix(theta1)))


        lit+=1
        s=sum((float(1.0)/m)*X.T*(sigmoid(X*theta)-y))/float(n)

    return theta
```

This is a logistic regression using the simple sigmoid function 1/(1+e^(-t)), I can not figure out what is the problem mainly with the function 'graD' part which does the regularized gradient descent, the result is not correct which is as follows:

```
lg(X,y,0.01,0.1,30)
Out[137]: 
matrix([[1000.10539375],
    [  49.33333333]])
```

and the data I input is:
(for X):
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
(for y):
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

Comment: What *is* the correct result, and where in the `while` execution do your intermediate results diverge from what you expected?

Comment: @Prune The correct result should be the first element of the matrix negative and the second element posotive

Comment: @Prune the specific value can not be determined before correctly calculated, and actually I found that during the descent, it just stop converging at some point, and I do not know where is the problem in while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in your code.

When calculating new theta values you need to use the simultaneous update. In your case changing theta0 you change theta, which then is used in theta1 calculation. It is wrong. You may need to use two temporary variables (or use a vectorized solution).

The cost function is also not correct. It should consist of two parts:

`y*log(h)` and `(1-y)*log(1-h)`.

As far as I know the cost function cannot be negative, so you don't need to calculate the absolute value of it.

The regularization looks wrong for me too.

Here is my code, it works for me.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1.0/(1+np.asmatrix(np.exp(-x)))

def graD(X,y,alpha,s0,numda):
    m=np.size(X,0)
    X0=X[:,0]
    X1=X[:,1:]

    theta=np.asmatrix(np.zeros(np.size(X,1))).T
    s=100
    lit=0

    s_history = []

    while s>s0 and lit<=10000:
        theta0=theta[0]
        theta1=theta[1:]

        sig = sigmoid(X*theta)

        theta0_temp = theta0 - (float(alpha)/m)*X0.T*(sig-y)
        theta1_temp = theta1 - (float(alpha)/m)*X1.T*(sig-y)   
        theta=np.vstack((np.asmatrix(theta0_temp),np.asmatrix(theta1_temp)))

        lit+=1

        # calculating the cost function
        part1 = np.multiply(y, np.log(sig))
        part2 = np.multiply((1 - y), np.log(1 - sig))

        s = (-part1 - part2).sum()/m        

        s_history.append(s)

    plt.plot(s_history)
    plt.title("Cost function")
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

    print theta
    print (-theta[0]/theta[1])  

    return theta

# Main module
_f = loadtxt('data/ex2data2_n_1.txt', delimiter=',')

_X, _y = _f[:,[0]], _f[:,[1]]

_m = np.shape(_X)[0]

# add a column of 1
_X = np.hstack((np.matrix(np.ones((_m, 1))),_X))
_y = np.matrix(_y)

_alpha = 0.01  

_n= np.shape(_X)[1]

_w = np.matrix(np.zeros((_n, 1)))

graD(_X, _y, _alpha, 0.1, 0.1)
```

Output:

```
theta = 
[[-5.51133636]
 [ 0.77301063]]

-theta0/theta1 = 
[[ 7.12970317]]    #this number is the decision boundary for the 1-D case
```

The cost function goes down as it should do:

[image: cost function of the logistic regression]

Comment: Oh! Yes, I made a big mistake here, thank you so much! I am new in ML, thank you for your help! :)